# Burn a disc box did not prompt up when inserting blank CD-R into optical drive

Tags: windows, formatting, optical-drive, disc

My laptop's optical drive did not prompt up anything when inserting blank CD-R

When I click my optical drive, this message shown:

[image: windows cannot read the disc]

So, it means optical drive detected the blank CD.

Normally this will show up like this one right?

[image: Windows Disc Info window]

But nothing show up for me.

However, my laptop's optical drive can read formatted disc.

This is my partition for optical drive, is it normal? Or something else wrong?

[image: Disk management]

Any help would be appreciated.

- Last time (about 4 months ago) I recall the box will prompt up.
- I checked my driver for optical drive is up to date
- I tried to uninstall the driver and restart computer, not working.

Comment: Which version of windows?

Comment: My laptop's windows version is Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the Autoplay issue check this setting :-

[image: Autoplay Options]
Settings >>> Devices >>> Autoplay

Make sure Autoplay is 'On' and that the Removable Drive option is set to 'Ask every time'

After checking that, and it still not behaving, try another blank CD-R. Also check that the drive you are using supports the type of disk. Ie, it's not a DVD you are using.

---

The error you've given states that the machine couldn't read the disc, not that it was specifically blank, which might be causing confusion. Check that the data side of the disc is clean, with no scratches.

Also check that the CD hasn't been used before. You can often see this by looking at the surface of the disc and noting if there is a colour change. See the image for an example.

[image: CD with recorded data]

Comment: My optical drive model name is Slimtype DVD A DA8A6SH.

Comment: Sorry, I done everything you said but still not working.

Comment: Do the settings match the above? Autoplay is turned on?

Comment: Ya Autoplay is on and Removable Drive option set to 'Ask every time'

Comment: Try another known blank CD-R.

Comment: I am so sorry, I try 3 brand new discs and restart my laptop but still not working. Any other solution?

Comment: The device is reading normal discs without an issue? is that correct?

Comment: Yes, can read it with no problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57331/discussion-between-steven-davison-and-coolwei).

Comment: Sorry I cannot upvote.

Comment: Now I can upvote. :)