# D:Drive Optical Drive Not Working

Tags: windows-10, drivers, compact-disc

My Optical Drive is currently on read-only, my question is why can't it write CD files anymore it used to?
The device when I click on drives is the following:

- DVD RW Drive(D:)

Computer Model

- Lenovo Ideapad 330

OS

- Windows 10

IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers

- Intel(R) 6th Generation Core Processor Family Platform I/O SATA AHCI Controller

CD Driver

- CD-ROM Drive HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GUEON

Recent Software Activity

- Installed a New Windows 10 Image

Did it work previously?

- It has written at least 5 CDs before.

Possible Hard Ware Issues:

- Lower Case is in need of repair. When the computer screen bends to back it distorts that section. However, when I tilt it in the right angle it reads CDs fine. So a possible hardware issue could be possible?
- Sometimes it fires up and keeps spinning, and the autoplay says to configure the data settings and says that D:\ is an invalid drive.

Software Checks:

- When I go into diskmgmt.msc it says that there is 0 bytes of 0 bytes in allocated space and when I try to increase the partition it says that its an invalid drive.

My Research:

- This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1201108/burn-a-disc-box-did-not-prompt-up-when-inserting-blank-cd-r-into-optical-drive) is helpful however it still does not solve it. I have kept trying different things still to no avail.
- I have watched videos like [these](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vNTHep2rAls&t=348s) that involve playing with the registry. Lots of them play with the registry, and I even sure one of them played with a partition size of the disc drive and allocating it.

Registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\cdrom]
"ImagePath"=hex(2):5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,64,00,72,\
  00,69,00,76,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,5c,00,63,00,64,00,72,00,6f,00,6d,00,2e,00,\
  73,00,79,00,73,00,00,00
"Type"=dword:00000001
"Start"=dword:00000001
"ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
"Group"="SCSI CDROM Class"
"Tag"=dword:00000001
"DisplayName"="@cdrom.inf,%cdrom_ServiceDesc%;CD-ROM Driver"
"Owners"=hex(7):63,00,64,00,72,00,6f,00,6d,00,2e,00,69,00,6e,00,66,00,00,00,00,\
  00
"AutoRun"=dword:00000001
"AutoRunAlwaysDisable"=hex(7):4e,00,45,00,43,00,20,00,20,00,20,00,20,00,20,00,\
  4d,00,42,00,52,00,2d,00,37,00,20,00,20,00,20,00,00,00,4e,00,45,00,43,00,20,\
  00,20,00,20,00,20,00,20,00,4d,00,42,00,52,00,2d,00,37,00,2e,00,34,00,20,00,\
  00,00,50,00,49,00,4f,00,4e,00,45,00,45,00,52,00,20,00,43,00,48,00,41,00,4e,\
  00,47,00,52,00,20,00,44,00,52,00,4d,00,2d,00,31,00,38,00,30,00,34,00,58,00,\
  00,00,50,00,49,00,4f,00,4e,00,45,00,45,00,52,00,20,00,43,00,44,00,2d,00,52,\
  00,4f,00,4d,00,20,00,44,00,52,00,4d,00,2d,00,36,00,33,00,32,00,34,00,58,00,\
  00,00,50,00,49,00,4f,00,4e,00,45,00,45,00,52,00,20,00,43,00,44,00,2d,00,52,\
  00,4f,00,4d,00,20,00,44,00,52,00,4d,00,2d,00,36,00,32,00,34,00,58,00,20,00,\
  00,00,54,00,4f,00,52,00,69,00,53,00,41,00,4e,00,20,00,43,00,44,00,2d,00,52,\
  00,4f,00,4d,00,20,00,43,00,44,00,52,00,5f,00,43,00,33,00,36,00,00,00,00,00
"BootFlags"=dword:00000080

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\cdrom\Parameters]
"DefaultDvdRegion"=dword:00000001
"WppRecorder_TraceGuid"="{a4196372-c3c4-42d5-87bf-7edb2e9bcc27}"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\cdrom\Parameters\Wdf]
"WdfMajorVersion"=dword:00000001
"WdfMinorVersion"=dword:0000000f
"TimeOfLastTelemetryLog"=hex(b):5e,98,68,de,3f,4e,d6,01

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\cdrom\Enum]
"0"="SCSI\\CdRom&Ven_HL-DT-ST&Prod_DVDRAM_GUE0N\\4&3a7994de&0&000100"
"Count"=dword:00000001
"NextInstance"=dword:00000001
```

If you need any more details please comment and provide where to access the information, I will be testing my D:\ on Ubuntu shortly.

From Ubuntu I can report that the drive is not working still.

Comment: I don;t use optical media much anymore, so last time I dug out the stack of CDR/DVDR from my closet, I found they had all gone bad. optical media only has a shelf life of 5-10 years depending on quality, before the dye starts to go bad, and the disks start to become translucent. May not be your issue, but worth considering.

Comment: @FrankThomas Yeah the question got closed with the generic reasoning of missing details however I wonder what exactly is missing? I put the Computer Model, the OS, the fact it has a CD-ROM optical drive, and the driver. I hate when they put these reasons and like offer not one bit of guidance to improve the question. This is a lack of good moderation.

Comment: @FrankThomas I love the CD-Drives thanks to the autoplay, and it can run certain programs on inserting. Unless the next windows 10 wipes that out, I heard USB's used to have an AutoPlay but now can't run programs on installation via an .inf file.

Comment: I have added extra juicy details like the registry key hahahaha any thoughts for keeping the questioning closed please let me know. Missing details keep it coming...

Comment: @ DavidPostill♦ is this enough detail? Tell me exactly what is it missing?

Comment: yeah, autorun from any kind of media is a major security vulnerability. for instance, the conficker worm used autorun to infect other systems. you are probably better off getting used to life without it.

Comment: Is the drive not writing, or not reading? If you run a Live Ubuntu disk can you write CDs? We need to narrow down if the issue is hardware or software. Using a live Linux distro will allow you to use different software, a different OS on the same hardware. If the drive still doesn't work in Linux your drive is bad. If the drive works in Linux then it's local software.

Comment: @EnlightenedFunky I do not think that your "@ DavidPostill" would have notified him. This feature works only if that person has commented.

Comment: @music2myear I am going to install ubuntu and test it out. I am still on windows I had Linux mint but I forgot the password hahaha, and deleted the Partition.

Comment: @music2myear It does not work... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact you have observed the drive does not work in either Windows or Linux, we can say with a reasonable level of certainty that the issue is with the hardware, either the drive or the system components the drive relies upon.

Whichever component is actually faulty, you will need to have a competent computer technician look at the device and diagnose and repair it.

Comment: Thanks not disagreeing there thanks very helpful.